# How to Parse a Boolean query inside a Span query in lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

I have to parse a Boolean query(AND) inside a Span query in lucene.
For instance: financial NEAR(5) (income AND tax) is what I am looking for. How should I parse this in lucene. I am using solr4.6 package with the patch Lucene-5205.

For the Boolean operand OR, I was able to implement it by changing the function _parsePureSpanClause in AbstractSpanQueryParser. Added the condition for making Boolean query valid inside a spanQuery:-

```
else if (t instanceof   SQPBooleanOpToken ) 
    {i++;} //go to next token
```

The above code makes sure that OR is not taken as a term in spanNear. Parsing the below query:-
[fileDataEnglish:profit (fileDataEnglish:maximum OR fileDataEnglish:income)]~3) gets converted to:-

spanNear([fileDataEnglish:profit, spanOr([fileDataEnglish:maximum, fileDataEnglish:income])], 3.3, true)

Can somebody tell how do I do the same for AND? What I know is that lucene converts AND queries like income AND profit to +income +profit. What should be the corresponding syntax for AND inside SPAN?
spanNear(+income +profit) ?? Also, which classes should be changed for this?

Answer (score 0):

AND is currently available only at the upper level.  For now, you'll need to use a proximity for "income" and "profit"

so

[financial [income tax]~5]~10

would be find "financial" within 10 words of the hit on "income" within 5 words of "tax".

Or you could just do:
[financial income tax]~10

find "financial" and "income" and "tax" within 10 words of each other.